# Control a chart with an input box, control an input box with a chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using a draggable highchart to portray some NBA payroll data.  If the bar gets dragged I would like to change an input box with a new salary. I've been going at this for a while, and have not made much progress.  I can get a draggable event to change an input box, but I cannot do the reverse.  I need some help.

I originally, started going a state change route and this was my thinking.  Basically, the chart can control a global, and the input can control the global. Then I just need to update the corresponding items in the DOM.

```
var state = {};
state.contractStructure = 'EQUAL'; // Could also be PROGRESSIVE, BACKEND, DIMINISHING
state.netIncome = <%= @team1_tax[:net_income] %>;
state.numYears = <%= @lookup_hash[:years]; %>;
state.incomeByYear = [];


function setNetIncome(value) {

  state.netIncome = value;
  if (state.contractStructure === 'EQUAL') {
     var perYearIncome = state.netIncome / numYears;
     for (var i = 0; i < state.numYears; i++) {
         state.incomeByYear[i] = perYearIncome
    }
  } else if (state.contractStructure === PROGRESSIVE) {
  }


  // Once all data is computed.
  // Loop through all input boxes and set input[i].value = state.incomeByYear[i]

}

Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('year-inputs')).forEach(element) {

   element.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

      var value = e.value; // this is the number typed intot he boxes
      var i = ??? //
      state.incomeByYear[i] = value

      // Once all data computed
      // Re-reneder the high chart with computed data

   }


})


function onNewContractDrag(newValue, year) {
    state.incomeByYear[year] = newValue
    state.netIncome // somehow adjust according to newValue

    // Need to update all boxes to reflect chagne in state
    // Loop through each one. Each one's value get set to state.incomeByYear[i]

}
```

Then it seemed like overkill, so I started investigating other ways.

I've created a JsFiddle, but I can only go from dragging to and input box. Should I go the state change route? JsFiddle route.

My js fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/AyUbx/3388/

Comment: so you want to update points depending on the values in your inputs? You should be able to do this using Point.update(). Look at first input here: http://jsfiddle.net/AyUbx/3389/

Comment: precisely.  Thanks, helps a lot.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński having a little issue using this method for all inputs. Mind taking a look? http://jsfiddle.net/twq6gb7d/

Comment: Could you please give more detailed info about the issue you have?

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I've bound all the inputs to the respective data, however, only the first function works (the function to control the first bar).  The second function is identical except for the input box id is different, yet it will not function correctly

Comment: You have to much callback functions. You can make this functionality with one callback function: http://jsfiddle.net/twq6gb7d/1/