# Only one function in highcharts will function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to manipulate a chart with input boxes.  Each input box should correspond to a bar.  In my code, I can get the first function at the bottom of the highcharts to work, but identical code with the bar changed and the input id doesnt work. Function in question is the last function with season-2 as id.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    animation: false
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['2016-17', '2017-18', '2018-19', '2019-20', '2020-21', '2021-22'],
    title: {
      text: 'Season'
    }
  },


  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: '$ Dollars'
    }
  }],

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderColor: '#2c3e50',
      point: {
        events: {
          drag: function(e) {
            $('#drag').html(
              'Dragging <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2) + '</b>');
              if (this.category == "2016-17"){
                $('#season-1').val(Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2));
              }
              if (this.category == "2017-18"){
                $('#season-2').val(Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2));
              } 
              if (this.category == "2018-19")
              {
               $('#season-3').val(Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2));
              } 
              if (this.category == "2019-20"){
            $('#season-4').val(Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2));
            } if (this.category == "2020-21"){
                $('#season-5').val(Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2));
            }

          },
          drop: function() {
            $('#drop').html(
              'In <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> was set to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '</b>');
          }
        }
      },
      stickyTracking: false
    },
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    },
    line: {
      cursor: 'ns-resize'
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    yDecimals: 2
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Salary Cap',
    data: [94000000, 102000000, 108000000, 109000000, 114000000]
  }, {
    name: 'Tax Cap',
    data: [113000000, 122000000, 130000000, 132000000, 139000000]
  }, {
    name: 'New Contract',
    data: [10996155, 10996155, 10996155, 10996155, 10996155],
    draggableY: true,
    // drag: function() { console.log(arguments); },
    dragMinY: 0,
    type: 'column',
    minPointLength: 2,
    color: 'whitesmoke'
  }, {
    name: 'Current Payroll',
    data: [110492645, 103423474, 97903566, 62944822, 28751775],
    //draggableX: true,
    draggableY: false,
    dragMinY: 0,
    type: 'column',
    minPointLength: 2,
    color: '#2c3e50'
  }]

}, function(chart) {
  $('#season-1').change(function() {
    var val = parseInt(this.value) || 0;
    chart.series[3].data[0].update({
      y: val
    });
  })
},
function(chart) {
  $('#season-2').change(function() {
    var val = parseInt(this.value) || 0;
    chart.series[3].data[1].update({
      y: val
    });
  })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/twq6gb7d/

Comment: Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886633/control-a-chart-with-an-input-box-control-an-input-box-with-a-chart?noredirect=1#comment67095169_39886633

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I isolated the `change` functions from inside the highcharts initialization function, and let JQuery handle it by selecting the container of the chart and calling the `highchart` function.

Snippet of the code:

```
    .... //rest of the code
    dragMinY: 0,
    type: 'column',
    minPointLength: 2,
    color: '#2c3e50'
  }]
}); //end of the highchart initialization

$('#season-1').change(function() {
  var val = parseInt(this.value) || 0;
  $('#container').highcharts().series[3].data[0].update({
    y: val
  });
});
... // other change functions
```

Working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/earlvon_lapura/h6bbuo6j/).